# Scroll horizontally both with vertical and horizontal scrolls with React

Tags: css, reactjs

Is there a good library or way to have the page to scroll horizontally, but with both horizontal and vertical mouse movements? This is an example of what we are trying to achieve https://qodeinteractive.com/catalog/manon/

Answer (score 0):

there is a nice package : https://github.com/xobotyi/react-scrollbars-custom

You will find what you want to do. However, you will need to setup it a little bit i think. Take a look at the API, it pretty nice done :)